# JQGrid How to prepopulate before adding new Record

Tags: jqgrid, insert

I am adding new data to jqgrid. The data is related to a customer, so new record must contain the customer id. Hence I want the popup form for adding record should come with customer code pre populated (readonly) . Customer Code is available in a dropdown list. 
I tried the following - added a custom button with a custom function AddRow (This is a borrowed code from Internet ). Inside the function I am using setColProp to set the CustomerId into the field. However, nothinng happens. Not even the popup appears.
Is there any easier way of doing the same thing?

```
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/service/OfficeData.asmx/GetDealer_SMS") %>',
                editurl: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/service/OfficeData.asmx/InsertDealer_SMS") %>',
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'POST',
                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
                ajaxEditOptions: { ContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', dataType: 'json' },
                serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                    //alert("Call");
                    if (postData.DealerCode === undefined) { postData.DealerCode = DealerCode; }
                    else {
                        postData.DealerCode = DealerCode;
                    }
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                },
                jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "d.rows", page: "d.page", total: "d.total", records: "d.records" },
                colNames: ['ID', 'DealerCode', 'Name', 'Designation', 'Address', 'EMail', 'Mobile'],
                colModel: [{ name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 10, align: 'left', editable: true, hidden: true,
                    editrules: { required: false },
                    editoptions: {
                        dataInit: function (element) {
                            $(element).attr("readonly", "readonly");
                        }
                    }
                },
                { name: 'DealerCode', index: 'DealerCode', width: 60, align: 'left', editable: true,
                    editrules: { required: true },
                    editoptions: {
                        dataInit: function (element) {
                            $(element).attr("readonly", "readonly");
                        }
                    }
                },
                { name: 'RecpName', index: 'RecpName', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true,
                    editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { size: 30, maxlength: 150 }
                },
                { name: 'RecpDesignation', index: 'RecpDesignation', width: 100, align: 'left', editable: true,
                    editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { size: 30, maxlength: 150 }
                },
                { name: 'RecpAddress', index: 'RecpAddress', width: 250, align: 'left', editable: true,
                    editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { size: 30, maxlength: 400 }
                },
                { name: 'RecpEMail', index: 'RecpEMail', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true,
                    editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { size: 30, maxlength: 150 }
                },
                { name: 'RecpMobile', index: 'RecpMobile', width: 100, align: 'left', editable: true,
                    editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { size: 30, maxlength: 30 }
                }],
                loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error while loading -' + errorThrown);
                },
                pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                rowNum: 20,
                rowList: [10, 20, 50],
                sortname: 'RecpName',
                sortorder: "asc",
                viewrecords: true,
                imgpath: '/scripts/themes/steel/images',
                caption: 'Dealer Recepient Details'
            }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false })

            .navButtonAdd('#pager',
    { caption: "Add",
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-plus",
 onClickButton: addRow,

  title: "",
  cursor: "pointer"
 }
 )
      .navButtonAdd('#pager',
        { caption: "Edit",
      buttonicon: "ui-icon-pencil",
     onClickButton: editRow,
     position: "last",
    title: "",
    cursor: "pointer"
    }
   ).navButtonAdd('#pager',
   { caption: "Delete",
   buttonicon: "ui-icon-trash",
   onClickButton: deleteRow,
   position: "last",
   title: "",
   cursor: "pointer"
  }
  );


            function addRow() {
                alert(DealerCode);
                $("#grid").jqGrid('setColProp', 'DealerCode', { editoptions: { readonly: true, size: 10, value: DealerCode} });


                $('#grid').jqGrid('editGridRow','new',
{ url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/service/OfficeData.asmx/InsertDealer_SMS") %>',
editData: {},
serializeEditData: function(data){
data.id = 0;
return $.param(data);
},
recreateForm: true,
beforeShowForm: function(form) {
$('#pData').hide();
$('#nData').hide();

},
beforeInitData: function(form) {},
closeAfterAdd: true,
reloadAfterSubmit:true,
afterSubmit : function(response, postdata)
{
var result = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');
var errors = "";
if (result.success == false) {
for (var i = 0; i < result.message.length; i++) {
errors += result.message[i] + "<br/>";
}
} else {
$('#msgbox').text('Entry has been added successfully');
$('#msgbox').dialog(
{ title: 'Success',
    modal: true,
buttons: {"Ok": function() {
$(this).dialog("close");}
}
});
}
// only used for adding new records
var newId = null;
return [result.success, errors, newId];
}
});


} // end of addRow
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```js
 jQuery("#subgridTable")
                .navButtonAdd('#pager',{
                    caption:"", 
                    title:"Add Row", 
                    buttonicon:"ui-icon-plus", 
                    onClickButton: function(){ 

// The next line loads the form I will use to add information to the table into a div called subgrid_popup_form_container

                        dialog = $("#subgrid_popup_form_container").load(ROOT + "/admin/contact/edit.do?id=0&sid=${station_id}");

// Then I use the dialog function from JQuery UI to get the form(div) into a modal dialog.
                        dialog.dialog({
                            modal:true,
                            height: minHeight,
                            width: minWidth,
                            zIndex: 2000,
                            title: 'Novo Contato',
                            close: function(event, ui) {dialog.empty()},
                        }); 
                    }, 
                    position:"last"
                })
```

In the **form Submit button** I add the information to the database (you may add it to your array or whatever) and then at the end I call `jQuery("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");` to refresh the grid with the brand new data.

In your case you can create the HTML form and make it populate the ID for you, then when you save the data and refresh the grid your new row will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Could solve it---

```
  }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, refresh: true, search: true },
        {
            ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', dataType: 'json' },
            serializeEditData: function (postData) {
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            },
            closeAfterEdit: false
        },
        {
            beforeInitData: function (formid) {
                $("#list").jqGrid('setColProp', 'DealerCode', { editoptions: { value:         
         DealerCode, readonly: 'readonly'} });
            },
            afterShowForm: function (formid) {
                $("#list").jqGrid('setColProp', 'DealerCode', { editable: false });
            },
            afterSubmit: function (response) {
                var myInfo = '<div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all">' +
             '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" ' +
                 'style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>' +
             response.responseText +
             '</div>',
    $infoTr = $("#TblGrid_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + ">tbody>tr.tinfo"),
    $infoTd = $infoTr.children("td.topinfo");
                $infoTd.html(myInfo);
                $infoTr.show();

                // display status message to 3 sec only
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $infoTr.slideUp("slow");
                }, 3000);

                return [true, "", ""]; // response should be interpreted as successful
            },
```